# Is there a way to make a scrollable section in dashboard?

Tags: scroll, dashboard, thingsboard, gauge

I created a dashboard on thingsboard, there I have some digital gauges. For now there is a small amount of them that are displayed on the dashboard. What if I have many of them?

What I want to have is a scrollable section that I can put all the gauges in so they will not take so much space. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

The image show what I have now, think that the two column will have many more gauges.

Comment: How did you add this donald widgets in just one widget ?

Comment: @SefaUn This is a snapshot of a dashboard, in the picture there are 6 digital gauge widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me, Go to you dashboard and do the following:

1. Click on edit (the orange circle with the pen in it).
2. Click on Manage Layouts (On the top left corner).
3. Add V in the right option there.

Now you will have right section, that is separate from the left section. If the right section will be scrollable it won't affect the left section.

**Note:** In this solution the both sides are not adjustable in size, it is a fixed size 50-50.